# Replace Http RestTemplate using Guicier injection [Dropwizard]

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, guice, dropwizard, inject

We are working on a drop-wizard application and use Guice for Injection.
I've the following http call and I am instantiating the the http client and rest template. Instead I am looking for ways for Guice to inject those objects. How can I do that ?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity request;
        headers.set("Accept", MEDIA_TYPE);
        request = new HttpEntity(jsonContent, headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, request, String.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would create factories for the objects that are frequently created and inject the factories as dependencies. For unit testing, you can mock the output of factories and have complete control over the code flow.

But if you want to inject `RestTemplate` as a direct dependency then you can write a module like this:

```
public MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    public RestTemplate providesRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
public MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(RestTemplate.class);
    }
}
```

First example uses Guice [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) annotation which I personally prefer. Second one uses a direct bind to the concrete class. Both achieve the same result and you can inject the dependency into a class as given below.

```
public MyClass {
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }
}
```